# pygame, screen not updating or filling with correct color

Tags: python, pygame

Trying to start a new pygame project. Very basic stuff. Just trying to color the screen. Currently the screen opens, and goes white. There are no errors in the console.
here is my code:

```
import sys

import pygame
from settings import Settings

def run_game():
  pygame.init()
  ai_settings = Settings()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
  pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

  while True:
  
    screen.fill((0,255,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():

      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip() # same result with .update

run_game()
```

id be happy if it would simply show a green screen. Any ideas what my issue could be?

Comment: Your program will never get past the `for` loop.  You need to put the `flip` call before the loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts There shouldn't be any events firing, also I moved it and it still doesn't turn the screen green

Comment: @TimRoberts No, this is not true. This is a nice application loop like in any tutorial.[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) is returning a list of the events currently in the queue and clears the queue.

Comment: The problem is not with your code, but with your system.

Comment: Don't forget to limit the FPS with `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` -> `clock.tick(60)`

Comment: @rabbid76 any idea where I should look to resolve this?

Comment: What version of pygame are you using? Did you try to update pygame? The current version is 2.1.0. Update with `pip3 install pygame --upgrade`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i was using 1.9.6! upgrading fixed it! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the most recent version of pygame fixed this.

```
pip3 install pygame --upgrade
```

thanks to @rabbid76 for the solution